# TFS only check in specific files and folders and not all pending changes

Tags: c#

I am still having problems communicating with TFS through my C# application. I am trying to work with PendingChanges to check in files created by my application but after hours of google research and reading I have yet to find a way to ONLY check in specific files. Whenever I do a check in, TFS simply checks in ALL items that are currently checked out PLUS the ones I tell it to check in. Is there a way to remove certain items from the PendingChanges object or create a completely new pendingchanges object with JUST the files I need checked in? This entire behavior of all or nothing seems to be quite ridiculous. Please help.

```
Workspace myWorkspace = createWorkspace();
// Show our pending changes.
PendingChange[] pendingChanges = myWorkspace.GetPendingChanges();
rt.Text += "Your current pending changes: \n";
foreach (string f in checkinItems)
{
    foreach (PendingChange pendingChange in pendingChanges)
    {
        if (Path.Combine(localPath, f) != pendingChange.LocalItem)
        {
            toCheckIn.Add(Path.Combine(localPath, f));
            rt.Text += "Found one!" + Path.Combine(localPath, f).ToString() + "\n";
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            rt.Text += pendingChange.LocalItem + " Not ours. \n";
        }
    }
}



myWorkspace.PendAdd(toCheckIn.ToArray(), true);


// Checkin the items we added.
int changesetNumber = myWorkspace.CheckIn(pendingChanges, currentUserName + ": " + toCheckIn + " from CokomImport");
rt.Text += "Checked in changeset " + changesetNumber;
```

This is the code I have so far. It filters out the stuff that I don't need but in the end it makes no difference because I need to check in the original PendingChanges with the stuff I need added to it.

Comment: In VS I can check in to TFS a specific file out of several checked-out ones - so it *must* be possible.

Comment: @Flobbo: Please show some code

Comment: If you're using VS2012, in the 'pending changes' window of the team explorer, you can explicitly 'exclude' files/folders etc. Which will not be checked in until you remove the exclusion.

Comment: @HansKesting: I totally agree, I just haven't found the solution yet. It's all nice and peachy through VS2010 but using the API it seems impossible.

Comment: `Workspace.Checkin` takes the changes to check-in (already pended) as its first argument. You're passing the original `pendingChanges` you got when you called `Workspace.GetPendingChanges()` - so yes, this will check in all your pending changes.  Did you mean to pass `toCheckIn.ToArray()` to checkin?